# Should I ever use exceptions in java if I can solve problem without them?

Tags: java

Are exceptions like goto in c don't use it if you don't have to or is it OK to use them as much you want to, and why?
Are they hard on CPU, memory or something else?

Comment: as the name suggest, they are OK to indicate an exception (to help make code more readable, for example)

Comment: If I can check-then-act to avoid an exception happening, then as a rule of thumb I do that. Weigh the pros and cons in each situation.

Comment: How would you avoid checked exceptions?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Currently I'm doing some easy thing, so I can turn varibales in to in to boolean with trim() and stiff like that in just few rows, but I was wondering what is better and couldn't find on google any clarification.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for narrowly-focused questions addressing a specific technical issue that can reasonably be expected to have a spot-on solution. The goal is to avoid open-ended discussions. So this question is not appropriate to this site. Voting to close as "too broad". This kind of topic should be taken to a discussion/forum site such as http://www.JavaRanch.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...don't use it if you don't have to or is it OK to use them as much you want to...

According to *Joshua Bloch's Effective Java*:

> Exceptions are, as their name implies, to be used only for exceptional
>   conditions; they should never be used for ordinary control flow.

In order to fully understand this, let's take a look on Java exception. In Java we can find three types of exceptions: *checked exceptions*, *runtime exceptions*, and
*errors*.

**Checked exceptions**: as their name implies, they should be checked/treated by the developer. Moreover, the compiler forces you to handle this exceptions by `try...catch` or propagating them upwards by marking the method with `throws` keyword. These kind of exceptions usually extend the builtin `Exception' class.

**Unchecked exceptions**: in this group enter both *runtime exceptions* and *errors*. The difference between checked exception and unchecked exceptions is that the compiler does not forces you to handle unchecked exceptions. Since they should be used to indicate programming errors, usually it is a good idea to not catch them at all and focus on preventing them. *Errors* are reserved for use by the JVM to indicate critical failures which usually prevent your program to be recoverable. All of the unchecked
exceptions should subclass `RuntimeException` class.

So, to give you a response to your first question, it is OK to use exceptions as long as it makes your code readable, more understandable. Moreover, you should be able to deal with exceptions, since compiler will force you to do so. This does not mean that you should throw exceptions whenever you want.

Now let's talk about performance. To repeat myself, exceptions should be used in exceptional cases. This means that they are not as performant as a single `if..else` would be. Using them wisely, you wont really notice a performance hit, overusing them can cause problems. Exceptions should never be used for control flow (`goto`s can be used for). In case of memory, every exception creates a new object, which should contain some information about the exception itself. Creating many exceptions would result in occupying more memory, but I don't think that this can be a problem nowadays.

> Should I ever use exceptions in java if I can solve problem without
>   them?

It depends, and is up to you on deciding against or in favor of them. Usually, exceptions are thrown to notify the lack of something (example: no money to withdraw from a credit card, non-existent file to open, etc.) In order to avoid using exceptions in these cases, it is a good idea to return on `Optional` of something.

This answer is based on *Joshua Bloch*'s *Effective Java* book. For more information I suggest reading the *Exceptions* chapter.

Answer (score 1):

You should regard exceptions as a tool that can help you make good software design, similar to data encapsulation (private fields with Getters/Setters), inheritance, interfaces, etc.

The idea of the exception concept in Java is to give you a good way of moving error handling to a spot in your code where it makes most sense. When you face a problem at some line of code, then the first thing you should ask yourself is: Should this method/class that I have here be responsible for handling the problem, or is there a better, more high-level place in my software that should handle it? If you find the latter to be the case, then throwing an exception to that higher-level instance is good design.

Think of it as this: Let's say someone at your work place gives you a pack of bills and tells you to add up the total billing amount. And then in the middle of the bills you find another document that is something completely different. In that case, it would make more sense to go to the person who gave you the pack of documents and let them handle it, instead of deciding for yourself what to do with it, because you may not know what exactly to do.

Example in software: Let's say you have a method that expects a birth date and should calculate the age of the person (difference to current date). But then you find that the given date is incorrect, for instance because it is in future. This method should not deal with fixing the problem, because you might not know how. Is this program a console program and you should print an error, or will it have a GUI? So, you throw an exception to a higher level of the application that knows if there is a GUI or not, and thus whether to print an error to console or show a dialog in the GUI. That's just a simple example, but I hope you get what I mean.

To sum up: Exceptions are nothing "bad" in Java. When used properly, they are a good thing that help you avoid putting responsibilities into objects that they shouldn't have.

Comment: Thank,I understand better nwo. Just one more thing do they slow down program.

Comment: they don't have a performance impact unless you do crazy stuff, but that applies to everything :)